# select tag seems to mess up my css

Tags: javascript, html, css

here's my page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head >
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.base.css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<style type="text/css">
ul, ol { margin-left:1.5em; padding-left:0px; }
li { margin-bottom:2.5em; }
body,
    html {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        color:#000;
        background:#a7a09a;
    }
#wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:1024px;
    background:#f5f5f5;
}

#sideBar{
    width:20%;
    height:1024px;
    background:red;
    display:block;
    float:right;
}
#mainContent{
    width:80%;
    height:1024px;
    background:blue;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
    * html #footer {
        height:1px;
    }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/modernizr.custom.05850.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js" > </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.19.min.js"></script>

<script  type="text/javascript"  src="Scripts/grid.locale-en.js" ></script>

<script   type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/json2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/linq.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.layout-latest.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sideBar">


    <select   id='listOfExistingViews'  />    


    <ul >


    <li>

TEST1

    </li>

    <li>

     TEST2
    </li>

    </ul>

    </div>
    <div id="mainContent"></div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

the problem is with the 'select' element as it doesn't allow the ul element to be displayed/rendered and the main container also doesnt retain its background color. everything seems to work fine though when the select element isnt used..:|
        what exactly am i missing over here....

Comment: First step in debugging HTML/CSS should be here: http://validator.w3.org/ What's with the double doctype?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/retributionxd/2QEuR/

Comment: i was playing around with doctypes...that wasnt the problem though....the select tag needs a closing tag apparently... here's to verbosity...:|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a valid `select` tag.

```
<select id="listOfExistingViews"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly open and close the select tag, and select has to be followed by options:

```
<select id='listOfExistingViews'>
 <option value='1'>TEST1</option>
 <option value='2'>TEST2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The only valid child element of `select` is `option` or `optgroup`, you can't have lists, headings, paragraphs, etc.

Comment: @SHAKIR Umm no, only `<option></option>` type elements should be inside a `select`

Comment: i had used <select   id='listOfExistingViews'  /> my intention was to close the tag there itself using the ubiquitous '/'.... apparently, that wasn't the case...

Comment: @WesleyMurch fair enough, I will do the same.  Though a select doesn't *have* to be followed by options.